# Por que o PHP não faz mais o parse de datas com "BRST"?

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

BRST significa "Brasília Summer Time"

Antes da versão 7.0.26, o PHP fazia o parse da seguinte string:

```
$date = new DateTime("Mon Jan 01 20:00:00 BRST 2017");
```

Depois dessa versão, o PHP retorna:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to 
parse time string (Mon Jan 01 20:00:00 BRST 2017) at position 4 (J): 
The timezone could not be found in the database in /in/c6K56:5
Stack trace:
#0 /in/c6K56(5): DateTime->__construct('Mon Jan 01 20:0...')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /in/c6K56 on line 5

Process exited with code 255.
```

Eu pesquisei no changelog, mas não consegui encontrar nenhuma explicação pra isso.

Exemplo:

https://3v4l.org/c6K56#v7026

Comment: Conseguir rodar na versão `7.1.10-1+ubuntu17.04.1+deb.sury.org+1`. https://postimg.org/image/c92dx7qyz/. No meu PC com a versão `7.1.12` 
não conseguir. Olhei rapidamente o `php.ini` e vi que as versões do `"Olson" Timezone Database` são diferentes, talvez tenham mudado isso. Talvez você possa alterar essa versão: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42219436 . `BST` funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Isso foi respondido aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48076970/why-php-does-not-parse-brst-dates-anymore

Basicamente, várias definições de timezone foram removidas [neste commit](https://github.com/eggert/tz/commit/c9e6ef07cc6f1062ddd032c96c5172f403c0058f#diff-109e03a0a154807a82e70bef80657ebbL27).

O PHP foi atualizado para seguir essas novas definições [neste commit](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/8e3260376c65b762a51eee7c30ab560dadefa1f6#diff-851fac022a0926b8a6dbe650a12e4f82L343).